# Why getSnapshotBeforeUpdate is nedded in react

Tags: reactjs, react-lifecycle

I am learning to react lifecycle methods but stuck at a query and not able to find the answer even after lots of research over the web.

As per the react official documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#getsnapshotbeforeupdate), it is said that the method getSnapshotBeforeUpdate is used to perform something just before the DOM commit. The snapshot returned by this function will be later used by componentDidUpdate.

**The query:**
The parameters 'prevProps' and 'prevState' are already present in method componentDidUpdate, then why does it need the help of function getSnapshotBeforeUpdate? I mean the function componentDidUpdate has necessary inputs to perform what getSnapshotBeforeUpdate is doing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Best,
Rahul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As clearly mentioned in the documentation with an example, the purpose of `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate` method is not to just get information from `prevProps` and/or `prevState`.

But it can be used to extract some information from the previous DOM (such as the current scroll position of a div) before the DOM is updated. Most cases, such DOM related values may not be covered by the `prevProps` or `prevState`.

When you consider only the `componentDidUpdate` method, the DOM has already updated (hence the name **Did**Update) when it's been called. So all the information related to the previous DOM has lost by that time.

Therefore the extracted information on previous DOM from `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate` can be passed to the `componentDidUpdate` method to use it there.

Comment: Thank you Udith for the answer. When you say DOM,  is it the virtual dom or the real dom?

Comment: As per my knowledge, it's the real DOM

Comment: @UdithGunaratna what are some real use cases of passing `prevProps` and `prevState` to `componentDidUpdate` ?